# How do I pause Andengine, but still get input?

Tags: android, andengine

In my game when I pause the game, I'd like to display three options (Resume, Restart and Menu) so I did this after calling `mEngine.stop()`:

```
Sprite resume = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, RM.resume, vertex){
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent event, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if(event.isActionDown()){
                    this.setScale(1.1f);
                    Log.i("Click","Click");

                }

                return super.onAreaTouched(event, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
            }
        };
```

But the Log "Click" never display. So I tried to do this with the Engine active and the Log displays correctly.

How can I stop my game (Modifier, Physics, Score) without using the `mEngine.stop()` method ?

Comment: Doesn't the engine gather input? Pausing it would pause input polling too, no?

Comment: Yes.. But so how I can stop the game (Modifier, Score, Physics) without using this method ?

Comment: Maybe that's the question you should ask, instead of "Why?".

Comment: It's fine for you now Mister ?

Comment: Just call me Byte, thanks. Mister Byte was my father.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `public void setIgnoreUpdate(final boolean pIgnoreUpdate);` method from the Entity class. The whole Scene is an entity and you attach all objects to it, so if you call `scene.setIgnoreUpdate(true)` all attached children will stop updating. Of course, you can selectively call this method only on Entities that you wish to pause. onTouch events should still work.